# How best to produce mutltiple selective outputs in different styles from single input file

Tags: multiple-files

I've been using [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) and LaTeX for academic work, and now I'm wondering whether I could use it to produce church service sheets. The catch is that I'd not just like do produce a single output -- which would be easy enough -- but to produce multiple different outputs from the same file, **with some content missed out in some outputs**.

To makes this clearer, I'd produce a single file with all the details of everything: titles of each item (e.g. name of the part of the liturgy, or song title and author), the content of each item (normally liturgy and song words), any rubrics, and other information like who is leading that item, and timings. Then I'd want to produce 4 versions:

1. a file for the service leader, and others leading individual items, including all of this detail
2. standard file for congregation, which excludes details of who is leading that item, and timings.
3. same as 2, but a large-print edition
4. (ideally) a version of 2 that uses Beamer to produce a version for projection on screen.

I realise I could produce a single LaTeX file and then write a script to post-process it and produce a cut-down file to use as the input for 2/3/4. And then write a script to process the files using various styles.

And [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127851/create-two-pdf-versions-of-classroom-slides-from-single-latex-file-teacher-and) is an example of producing two different styled outputs from the same TeX input, and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13184/options-for-building-multiple-documents-from-the-same-content-with-different-lay) does something similar too.

But my question is this: is there a sensible mechanism within LaTeX itself to produce different outputs some of which ignore the input content? (I know that metadata, such as `\author`, can be set in the preamble, and can be ignored my class definitions of `\maketitle`, but there will be lots of items with titles and authors.)

Comment: The other day I saw a mention of a package which allows (simulates?) opening multiple files for random writes from w/in a single typesetting run....