# TOC and Subfiles: which TOC pkg for unique TOC compilation with each subfile?

Tags: table-of-contents, compiling, subfiles, multiple-files

The [Subfiles package](ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf) makes compiling individual parts of a LaTex document convenient. The package works so that each subfile inherits the master preamble `main.tex` and the user is able to compile individual files separately. The package itself has no mention about TOCs for separate parts that are compiled.

Independent TOCs with Subfiles pkg must have some convenient solution. The options contain minitoc, shorttoc and titletoc, more in [comment](ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf).

**Which TOC package to use with Subfiles pkg to outline the document more conveniently consisting of multiple files?**

Comment: it seems that `tableof` and `etoc` works fine. `titletoc` too. And `minitoc` if each file is a section-like (part, chapter ...). I am not sure about compatibilite   with non standard class (for `minitoc` and `titletoc`).

Answer (score 7):

One can have `independent TOCs` without using any package, we need just to add in the main file

```
\tableofcontents
\let\tableofcontents\relax
```

---

**With packages**

Here are examples of how one can use packages

**1- tableof. (edited)** :

With the two lines approach above, one can compile separately each included sub-file, and it will have its own TOC. And the main file will have a global TOC. If that's what is wanted no need to read further.

If however one wants the included files to have their own TOC also in the main file, one can use [tableof](http://ctan.org/pkg/tableof) in the following, somewhat convoluted way. The constraints are:

1. `tableof` does not modify the book class default `\tableofcontents`, which, when used once displays the TOC but also erases the `.toc` file until the end of the document, so one can not use it twice.
2. `tableof` has its own additional commands such as `\tableoftaggedcontents` or `\tableof`. By themselves these commands display a TOC but do not open a `.toc` file for write. One must use, if no `\tableofcontents` command has been used, the package `\tofOpenTocFileForWrite`.
3. If one uses `\tofOpenTocFileForWrite`, after it `\tableofcontents` displays an empty TOC, one must use the package commands such as `\tableoftaggedcontents` or `\tableof` rather.
4. The latter commands do not print a heading, this can be done by the user with a `\section*` or a `\chapter*` etc...

If one insists despite the above constraints to use `tableof` package, here is how to do it. I have made it so that the included files are supposed to have only one chapter, and their TOC is for the contents of this chapter.

To test this and other examples make sure to start from a clean state with no auxiliary files. And as usual with TOCs, at least two compilations are needed, be it for the main file or the subfiles, if compiled individually. Naturally the numbering of sections and chapters will not be the same in the main file as it is in individually compiled subfiles.

**main file myfile.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tableof}
\AtBeginDocument{\tofOpenTocFileForWrite}% see tableof's doc
\begin{document}
\tableof{}% replaces book class \tableofcontents, which one
% can not use after \tofOpenTocFileForWrite
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Baz}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subfile{myfile1}
\subfile{myfile2}
\subfile{myfile3}
\end{document}
```

**myfile1.tex**

```
% main file is called myfile.tex
% this is myfile1.tex
\documentclass[myfile]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo1}
\tableof{myfile1}
\toftagstart{myfile1}
\section{Bar1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Baz1}
\lipsum[3-4]
\toftagstop{myfile1}
\end{document}
```

**myfile2.tex**

```
% main file is called myfile.tex
% this is myfile2.tex
\documentclass[myfile]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo2}
\tableof{myfile2}
\toftagstart{myfile2}
\section{Bar2}
\lipsum[5-6]
\section{Baz2}
\lipsum[7-8]
\toftagstop{myfile2}
\end{document}
```

**myfile3.tex**

```
% main file is called myfile.tex
% this is myfile3.tex
\documentclass[myfile]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo3}
\tableof{myfile3}
\toftagstart{myfile3}
\section{Bar3}
\lipsum[9-10]
\section{Baz3}
\lipsum[10-11]
\toftagstop{myfile3}
\end{document}
```

---

**2- titletoc**

**main file myfile.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%------
\usepackage{titletoc}
\startcontents
\begin{document}
%------
\printcontents{}{-1}{% parts are add to toc
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}%
\chapter*{\contentsname}%  or section ... 
}
%\renewcommand{\printcontents}[4][default]{} %if you don't want partial tocs
%------
\part{one}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Baz}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subfile{myfile1}
\subfile{myfile2}
\subfile{myfile3}
\end{document}
```

**myfile1.tex**

```
\documentclass[myfile]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
%------
\printcontents{}{-1}{%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}%
\chapter*{\contentsname}% or section ... 
}
%------
\chapter{Foo1}
\section{Bar1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Baz1}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

**myfile2.tex**

```
\documentclass[myfile]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
%------
\printcontents{}{-1}{%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}%
\chapter*{\contentsname}% or section ... 
}
%------
\chapter{Foo2}
\section{Bar2}
\lipsum[5-6]
\section{Baz2}
\lipsum[7-8]
\end{document}
```

**myfile3.tex**

```
\documentclass[myfile]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
%------
\printcontents{}{-1}{%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}%
\chapter*{\contentsname}% or section ... 
}
%------
\chapter{Foo3}
\section{Bar3}
\lipsum[9-10]
\section{Baz3}
\lipsum[10-11]
\end{document}
```

---

**3- minitoc** we add in the main file

```
\usepackage{minitoc}
\dominitoc
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\let\tableofcontents\relax
```

and in subfiles we add just `\tableofcontents`.

## Further reading

- [Documentation for tableof](ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tableof/tableof.pdf)
- [Minitoc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) and its [README](ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/minitoc/README)

Comment: in the method with `tableof`, the main file (not `file1`, etc...) should contain in its preamble `\AtBeginDocument{\tofOpenTocFileForWrite}` (cf doc of `tableof`; perhaps it worked for you because the files had initially been compiled while they contain a `\tableofcontents` command ? but starting with a clean state with no auxiliary file, the current code, as explained in `tableof`'s doc will not create the needed `.toc` file)

Comment: @jfbu thanks I'll see. you can edit my answer.

Comment: at first I wasn't sure what the OP was asking for. May I edit the tableof part of your answer ? (I saw your edit following my comment, but if you check you will see something else is needed like `\toftagstop`; thus your simpler no package answer is better anyhow).

Comment: @jfbu feel free,  I add `\toftagstop` as a note in my answer, answer that was given as example of demonstration, of course one should think also in toc heading and so.

Comment: I cannot understand which part of the example belong to tableof package and which parts are integral to latex/tex. Is this `"\tableofcontents
\let\tableofcontents\relax"` an example about tex/latex functionality while the part starting with `"1- tableof. (edited) :"` begins tableof functionality demonstration? Alas the minitoc pkg is also used: so this demonstrates the tableof-minitoc functionalatiy for TOC with subfiles? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @hhh first part `\tableofcontents \let\tableofcontents\relax` without any package (`latex functionality`) part 2 is with packges 3 example given `tableof`, `titletoc` and `minitoc`.  IMHO there is no need to any package if you don't look for partials tocs.

Comment: @touhami is the part 2 example meant to use all of the packages together or each separately? The myfile* are for each 1-3 demonstration about tableof, titletoc and minitoc i.e. not just for tableof? This distinction is somewhat confusing to me (trying to get minimal examples for each demonstration running).

Comment: @hhh answer updated.

Comment: As of `"With the two lines approach above, one can compile separately each included sub-file, and it will have its own TOC. And the main file will have a global TOC."` -- I am able to get precisely what I want with tableof but I am not able get this working with only the first two lines, I uncommented all `tableof-\toftagstart-\toftagstop{myfile3}` parts and no tableofcontents (no main TOC, no sub TOCs) produced. Can you clarify the initial parts?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment,  but if you don't want package you need to remove command related to the package `tableof` or `tiletoc` (for `titletoc` these line between commented dush rules and for `tableof` commands with `of` like `\...of...` then add `\tableofcontents \let\tableofcontents\relax` in the main file and `\tableofcontents` in each subfile.

Comment: @touhami do I misunderstand the first sentence of your answer? This [paste](http://pastebin.com/Me8cYz3r) demonstrates about how I see it so far -- it does not work at all so I am sure I am misunderstanding the initial part. Can you help to clarify it? I have demonstrated my understanding [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285741/2956) where I try to keep my ideas separate because of possible misunderstandings: `\let...\relax` structure in the case of `\tableofcontents` removes the value so far assigned to it, is it right? Then it assigns new vals until the next `\tableofc..\let\...\relax`?

Comment: The minitoc demonstration not working, codes as instructed copied to [here](http://pastebin.com/E1wKbzXa) -- only the main TOC appearing while the sub-TOCs not appearing.

Answer (score 3):

This outlines the [touhami](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/284781/2956): firstly the basic functionality of the main about `\let\relax` while the last parts demonstrate the subfiles pkg and TOC pkgs separately.

## Main

The `\tableofcontents` prints the tableofcontents to the whole document. The `\let\tableofcontents\relax` works like pointing to /dev/null with lazy evaluation, `"at the point of definition"` and more in [What is the difference between \let and \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def) and  [What does \relax do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96501/what-does-relax-do).

## Demonstrations

[0th demonstration] `"it seems that tableof and etoc works fine"` comment by touhami, [etoc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) and [tableof](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tableof). Demonstration to be done.

[1st demonstration] [Documentation for tableof](ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tableof/tableof.pdf)

> [image]
>
> *Tableof demonstration worked. The left is the main TOC while the right is the sub-TOC.*

[2nd demonstration] [Documentation for titletoc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc)

> The titletoc demonstration has the same main TOC over all TOCs, no sub-TOCs for each chapter, not working elegantly where succint subTOCs outline each chapter (not the same TOC repeating all the time).
>
> [image]

[3th demonstration] [Minitoc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) and its [README](ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/minitoc/README)

> *[Trial 1]* Not printing the sub-TOCs with Minitoc, more [here](http://pastebin.com/E1wKbzXa).
>
> [image]
>
> *The minitoc shows the main TOC correctly while repeating the sub-TOCs, the goal is to outline only the relevant parts of each chapter.*

Comment: I am confused now. What do you with `sub-tocs`? `titletoc` works for me the same as `Tableof`. For minitoc i will add example later. if you can make it more clear.

Comment: `minitoc` should works too for  you but i think you are looking for partials tocs (minitoc of each chapter)?

Comment: @touhami added a picture about the terminology explaining the terms `"main TOC"` and `"sub-TOC"`, my terminology, I don't know better words to describe them.

Comment: OK. I can see it now, I think you look for partials tocs that for seperate subfiles will be as main tocs. The problem here, is that subfiles should be (let say) section-like (part, chapter or section) see my first comment http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284773/toc-and-subfiles-which-toc-pkg-for-unique-toc-compilation-with-each-subfile/285741?noredirect=1#comment687264_284773. This is not necessary for `tableof` and `titletoc`

Comment: As you can see in 1st image, there will be a problem : partial toc is after chapter heading `Foo2`, now this is not one want if  the subfiles are compiled seperate no? I think it's time to edit the question or start another one with MWE of main file, subfiles and how you want it works.

Comment: Please make the problem with `titletoc` more clear. For me no problem.

Comment: @touhami added more information and a demonstration with a picture about `titletoc` (directly used your second codes without any change i.e. `"2 - titletoc"`), is it clear now?

Comment: I see it now. I will edit the code later.