# Subfiles package and ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, subfiles, etoc

I'm using the Subfiles package to compile a relatively large document in smaller steps. Each subfile is actually a chapter of the document. I would like to have a ToC in each chapter (in addition to the general ToC). I've used the lines

```
% !TEX encoding = IsoLatin9
\documentclass[./main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\let\tableofcontents\relax
\chapter{My first chapter}
...
```

in a chapter, and I obtain indeed a ToC for the chapter, but it is placed after a header "Contents" and before the title of the chapter. Moreover, the ("Contents" + ToC) is placed in a different page with respect to the title of the chapter.
I would like to obtain:

- Title of the chapter ("My first chapter" in the above example)
- ToC of the chapter (if possible, without the heading "Contents")
- beginning of the text of the chapter
  in this order and all on the same page.
  Is that possible?

Comment: Related (if not duplicated) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284773/toc-and-subfiles-which-toc-pkg-for-unique-toc-compilation-with-each-subfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to customize the local TOCs of the subfiles as required using the package `etoc`

Assuming that you have the main book file in the directory `BOOK` and the chapters in a sub-directory `chapters`

[image: t2]

you will get

**Full TOC of the book**

[image: mt]

**Chapter 1**

[image: c1]

**Chapter 2**

[image: c2]

This is   `full_book-2021.tex`

```
 %% full_book-2021.tex in its own directory BOOK

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{etoc} % for local TOC

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{subfiles} 

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \etocsettocstyle{}{} % now only local tocs
        
    \subfile{./chapters/chapter1}  % chapter 1  file in  BOOK/chapters/ subdirectory
    
    \subfile{./chapters/chapter2}  % chapter 2  file in  BOOK/chapters/ subdirectory

\end{document}
```

These are the chapter subfiles

```
%% chapter1.tex in /chapters subdirectory

\documentclass[../full-book-2021.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{My First Chapter}

\etocsettocstyle{% before code
    \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}
    \vspace*{-4\baselineskip}
    \section*{}
}
{% after code
    \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
}

\localtableofcontents
    
3. \kant[3-5]

\section{Sec1Ch1 Blue}

4. \kant[4-9]

\section{Sec2Ch1 Green}

5. \kant[5-11]  
    
\end{document}
```

and

```
%% chapter2.tex in /chapters subdirectory

\documentclass[../full-book-2021.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
        
    \etocsettocstyle{% before code
        \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}
        \vspace*{-4\baselineskip}
        \section*{}
    }
    {% after code
        \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}
        \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
    }
    
    
    \chapter{My Second Chapter}
    \localtableofcontents
    
    6. \kant[6-12]
    
    \section{Sec1Ch2 Red}
    
    7. \kant[7-14]
    
    \section{Sec2Ch2 Yellow}
    
    8. \kant[8-16]  
    
\end{document}
```